# Unable to get data from Json string in sql server database

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2017-express

I am trying to get all the fileDisplayName value from my data set column which has json string.

```
select 
id_ref id,
JSON_VALUE(cast(data_map as varchar(max)),'$.dataMap."4805".fileDisplayName') Attachments,
data_map dataa
from action_data where id_ref = 54432;
```

tried to but failed. my string value in column

```
"4805":{
   "@class":"com.tbitsglobal.dms.persistence.entities.datatypes.FileDataList",
   "id":0,
   "value":[
      {
         "@class":"com.tbitsglobal.dms.persistence.entities.datatypes.FileData",
         "id":0,
         "value":"28b1d5fb-d4b9-4d2b-8f70-cca1ecc6b64a",
         "checkSum":"91df90d0d72b71d46a633150d3f94117",
         "fileDisplayName":"KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0003.pdf",
         "fileUploadTime":1571372081959,
         "fileSize":101032,
         "fileProperties":null
      },
      {
         "@class":"com.tbitsglobal.dms.persistence.entities.datatypes.FileData",
         "id":0,
         "value":"4a6eabd6-9df8-4ce7-9eb0-25e6875a5a64",
         "checkSum":"a941428a17726c157915293db64aaca9",
         "fileDisplayName":"KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0001.pdf",
         "fileUploadTime":1571372082185,
         "fileSize":85028,
         "fileProperties":null
      },
      {
         "@class":"com.tbitsglobal.dms.persistence.entities.datatypes.FileData",
         "id":0,
         "value":"fb9a37e8-65b8-47a7-8e57-577c5aa4f162",
         "checkSum":"2f0036e074f28d22247608581aeac9ca",
         "fileDisplayName":"KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0002.pdf",
         "fileUploadTime":1571372082186,
         "fileSize":86907,
         "fileProperties":null
      }
   ]
},
```

excepted result
All the fileDisplayName value from field having id - 4805
Result :

```
KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0003.pdf
KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0001.pdf
KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0002.pdf
```

Comment: editing is required.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without actual table structure, but if I understand you correctly, the next approach may help to get your expected results. You need to parse `"value"` JSON array with additional `APPLY` operator using `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema definition (the `WITH` clause):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
   data_map nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Data
   (data_map)
VALUES
   (
N'{
   "4805": {
       "@class":"com.tbitsglobal.dms.persistence.entities.datatypes.FileDataList",
       "id":0,
       "value":[
           {
           "@class":"com.tbitsglobal.dms.persistence.entities.datatypes.FileData","id":0,"value":"28b1d5fb-d4b9-4d2b-8f70-cca1ecc6b64a","checkSum":"91df90d0d72b71d46a633150d3f94117","fileDisplayName":"KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0003.pdf","fileUploadTime":1571372081959,"fileSize":101032,"fileProperties":null
           },
           {
           "@class":"com.tbitsglobal.dms.persistence.entities.datatypes.FileData","id":0,"value":"4a6eabd6-9df8-4ce7-9eb0-25e6875a5a64","checkSum":"a941428a17726c157915293db64aaca9","fileDisplayName":"KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0001.pdf","fileUploadTime":1571372082185,"fileSize":85028,"fileProperties":null
           },
           {
           "@class":"com.tbitsglobal.dms.persistence.entities.datatypes.FileData","id":0,"value":"fb9a37e8-65b8-47a7-8e57-577c5aa4f162","checkSum":"2f0036e074f28d22247608581aeac9ca","fileDisplayName":"KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0002.pdf","fileUploadTime":1571372082186,"fileSize":86907,"fileProperties":null
           }
       ]
   }
}'
)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT j.*
FROM #Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.data_map, '$."4805".value') WITH (
   fileDisplayName nvarchar(max) '$.fileDisplayName'
) j
```

Output:

```
fileDisplayName
KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0003.pdf
KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0001.pdf
KSTPP-LTP-LTSO-L-622-0002.pdf
```